# launch VBS script after PC startup

Tags: vbscript

I want launch my simple VBS script after PC startup (Win XP). I don't want put this script in C:\Documents and Settings\%UserName%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

I want do it in script, it is possible?

```
Script:<br>
Dim oShell<br>
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")<br>
oShell.run "notepad.exe c:\text.txt"
```

Comment: is the PC joined to a domain? If so, couldn't you use a network policy / login script?

Answer (score 7):

You will either have to put it in the Startup folder or run it from the registry.

For all users, use registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`.

For the current user, use registry key `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Comment: the question is how to run vbs script on startup not from where

Answer (score 6):

**In-depth**

**How to Automate VBScripts to run at startup.**

*Step 1*

- Click `Start -> Run -> cmd` or Click `search` and type `cmd`
- Press enter
- Type `assoc .vbs` in command prompt
  Which should print `.vbs=VBSFile`
- Type `ftype VBSFile` in command prompt

which should print:

```
vbsfile="%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*
```

So, now you know that your vbscript files open with WScript by default.

- In command-prompt, type:

  reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\WScript.exe /s

If you do not see this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\WScript.exe
    (Standard)    REG_SZ    "%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*
```

Then you need to do the following, if the above is what you see, then you can skip and go to *step 3*:

*Step 2*

- Go to:

  Start

  Run
- Type in:

  regedit
- Select regedit press `enter` (or double-click regedit) and allow the
  program to make changes to your computer
- Navigate to:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\WScript.exe` (If WScript.exe key does not exist, right-click Applications and create new key, rename it to WScript.exe)

- In the empty space on the right, where there are values, right-click
  and
- Choose new
- Select String Value
- Under Name where New Value #1 is highlighted, rename by typing
  (Standard)
- Under Data, double click the empty value and enter the value you got
  from the previous step

> "%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*

*Step 3*

- If you do not have regedit open,

Go to:

- Start
- Run

Type in:

```
regedit
```

Select app, press enter and allow the program to make changes to your computer

- Else, if regedit is open, then:
- Navigate to:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

- Right click the run folder
- in the empty space on the right, where there are values, right-click
  and choose new
- Select Expandable String Value
- Under Name where New Value #1 is highlighted, rename by typing your
  own name e.g. myscript
- under Data, double click the empty value and enter this
- Make sure its type is REG_EXPAND_SZ, i.e. an expanded string

> ```
> "%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "C:\Users\me\myFolder\mySub-folder\myFile.vbs" "%1" %*
> ```

- Restart your machine. Your vbs should run automatically

*Notes:*

- make sure .VBS is added to the Path environment variable
- if you want to use cscript instead, In step 2  type:

  reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\cscript.exe /s

...instead and proceed, taking note to replace WScript with cscript where relevant
i.e. this query:

```
reg query HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\cscript.exe /s
```

Should produce this result:

```
(Standard)    REG_SZ    "C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe" "%1" %*
```

- If your key and/or value is messed up you can always right-click the
  messed up item and delete it. If you however want to use the
  terminal, you can always follow: http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html
- To check if WScript is one of the startup apps, press ctrl+alt+delete, choose the Task Manager, click on Startup. You should see Microsoft Windows Based Script Host listed.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the real clear answer! I was following your answer until step 2(create new). I received an error `Cannot create value: Error writing to the registry`. **PS:** I tried putting my VBs file on the startup path but required administor account which I don't have. Any idea what else can I do to run the file on start up?

Comment: Hi perhaps your company e.g. any client of mine would never give full administrator rights to employees so that they can alter the behaviour of a machine. If you would like to go ahead with this you will have to ask the owner of that laptop for permission or if perchance if it is your own laptop you would then need to change permissions which is another topic altogether

Answer (score 3):

Easy Way :

Make a bat file

```
WScript.exe "Path\to\your\script.vbs"
```

add it to startup from gpedit.msc

Answer (score 1):

Just an appoinment, everybody probalby just know already.

HKLM is for any user on the machine, because means Local Machine

HKCU is just for the current user.

Comment: the question is how to run vbs script on startup not from where

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the start of your vbs script
Change the end of myKey to whatever you want to call the registry key

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myKey = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\MyVbsScript"
WshShell.RegWrite myKey,WScript.ScriptFullName,"REG_SZ"
```

Answer (score -1):

**Task Scheduler** Alternative

No script is needed, create a new task ([Task Scheduler 1.0 (learn.microsoft.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-1-0-examples) for instruction). Then "Create a task" and populate at least these details:

```
New Trigger:  At Login
New Action -> Action:         Start A Program
              Program/Script:  notepad.exe
              Arguments:       text.txt
              Start in:        c:\
```

Software: Windows 10, Task Scheduler 1.0

Answer (score -3):

you can fire a vbscipt from registry or startup by

```
WScript C:\somefloder\somefolder2\yourscript.vbs
```

you can put this line in a value on

For all the users on the machine HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

for the current user HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run