# vbs sript error with editing registry

Tags: vbscript, windows-10, registry

i have problem with writing a new string value with a vbs script to registry. In regestry editor i can make it manualy so its not some permission issues.

There is what i came up with.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
myKey = "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\WScript.exe\UserData"
WshShell.RegWrite myKey, some-value,"REG_SZ"
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

When i try to run it i get this error message.

Invalid root in registry key "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\WScript.exeyUserData".

Code: 800700005

Source: WshShell.RegWrite

I came from these sources:

[launch VBS script after PC startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13706267/launch-vbs-script-after-pc-startup)

https://ss64.com/vb/regwrite.html

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: `800700005` is "access denied". Your script needs admin permissions to be allowed to write to this part of the registry. I am pretty sure the error actually says "access denied", too.